# Font Identification: Wix Website

Tags: font-identification

One of the default fonts included in the Wix themes when building your site looks like this:

[image]

Can someone identify? Looks very familiar but not having any luck with pinpointing, thanks!

Comment: You Can use pretty much any major browser to inspect a website and see what font that is as long as it's not an image. There are even browser plugins [1](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-finder/bhiichidigehdgphoambhjbekalahgha?hl=en), [2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en) that simply give you font related info

Comment: Now I have had to see the word "Wix" before breakfast :(

Comment: Hi Ian Crvenkovic, we have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

font style of "Sophisticated"

Questrial Plain via https://www.fontzillion.com/fonts/admix-designs/questrial?utm_source=fontsquirrel.com&utm_medium=matcherator_link&utm_campaign=questrial

Author of font is Admix Designs

[image]

fontstyle of "A seasoned world traveler, refined and cultured"

Janna™ by Linotype via https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/janna/?utm_source=fontsquirrel.com&utm_medium=matcherator_link&utm_campaign=janna

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As with any website, you can use developer tools (Firefox and Chrome) to view the source code of the web page. This includes the CSS styles (font, color hex, etc..).

In Chrome you can simply `right click` on any element of a web page, select `Inspect`, then go and view the font style of that element.

[image]